# How to configure MySQL isolation level on Polars with connector-x and the number of python threads

Tags: python-polars

Is there any way to configure MySQL isolation level on connector-x with Polars?

I want to start a lot of queries in db, until now I use sqlalchemy-pymysql with isolation level READ UNCOMMITTED config because I don't want to block any table in production db.

Is it possible to configure this in polars.read_database_uri()?

Other thing is, connector-x make use of ThreadPoolExecutor under the hood? Or use something that I can configure the number of the threads manually to makes the queries?

*PS: I can't flag connector-x here -> https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x*

Comment: maybe prepend whatever the mysql statements is to get `READ UNCOMMITTED` mode at the beginning of your query? I'm just guessing though since I don't use mysql.

Comment: This generally works, but, before connector-x make the query, it does SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (your query). This happens because connector-x will get the schema from your table and the query size for memory allocation, It works like this to optimize memory. When I try to set up isolation level on query start, MySQL give me syntax errors 